# How can I store multiple values in a single label in VB 2010?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, label

I am making a program that stores recipe information to be saved and loaded accordingly.

I would like to know if there is a way to store different ingredients and amounts from 2 separate text boxes.

My layout can be found here:

**http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a510/HerpDerp691/lol_zps23f0e2cf.png**

This is the code for when the 'Add' button is pressed.

```
 Private Sub AddIngredientButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddIngredientButton.Click


    IngredientsLabel.Text = AddIngredientBox.Text

    IngredientsAmountLabel.Text = AmountBox.Text
End Sub
```

I hope this helps! If you require any more code then just ask.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like you need to use a ListView control and add items to that in two different columns

Comment: sorry, i am such a noob. Can you please tell me what that is. I have very very little knowledge about vb. Thanks

Comment: I have just look it up. Thanks

Comment: Could you answer this question saying that so i can list it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use a [ListView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) in with [View = Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so that it lists the ingredients in tabular format e.g.

```
Ingredient               |Amount
-------------------------|-----------------------
foo                      |1kg
bar                      |35g
```